# How can i convert yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:sszzz to timestamp with php?

Tags: date, timestamp, unix-timestamp, php

I have tried this code:

```
$dateFromDB = '2012-06-22T14:06:55+00:00';

$newDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:sszzz', $dateFromDB);
$date = $newDate->format('U'); // convert to timestamp

echo $date;
```

but gave me this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object in...

What is the problem with this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strtotime()` should be able to parse that nicely and returns Unix timestamp.

```
<?php
$timestamp = strtotime('2012-06-22T14:06:55+00:00');

echo $timestamp;  // prints: 1340374015
```

Answer (score 3):

If you need to use DateTime please try it procedural way:

```php
$dateFromDB = '2012-06-22T14:06:55+00:00';  
$timestamp = date_create_from_format('Y-m-d\TH:i:sP', $dateFromDB);
// To get Unix timespamp
echo date_format($timestamp, 'U');
// To get user-formated Date
echo date("d.m.Y H:i:s", date_format($timestamp, 'U'));
```

Answer (score 2):

or if you really need to use DateTime

```
$dateFromDB = '2012-06-22T14:06:55+00:00';

$newDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d?H:i:sP', $dateFromDB);
$date = $newDate->format('U'); // convert to timestamp

echo $date;
```

Comment: i don't really need datetime... what is the fastest version?

Comment: In this case i would worry more about which one is the working version. You could benchmark it but it will be a waste of time imo.

Comment: I personally always prefer classes over raw functions.

Comment: both of them are working. i think i will use strtotime because it occupies less code space.  `echo strtotime($dateFromDB);`

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
$date = strtotime($dateFromDB);
```